# Include Neo4j server in jar

Tags: rest, clojure, neo4j

I am creating a Clojure application that uses Neo4J via the REST API, and I would like to include Neo4j as a dependency.

I read that it is possible to embed Neo4j http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/tutorials-java-embedded.html

But is it also possible to use the REST API that way?

This is what my `project.clj` looks like:

```
(defproject example "0.1.0-SNAPSHOT"
  :dependencies [[org.clojure/clojure "1.5.1"]
                 [clojurewerkz/neocons "2.0.0"]
                 [org.neo4j.app/neo4j-server "2.1.0-M01"]]
  :aliases {"neo4j" ["run" "-m" "org.neo4j.server.Bootstrapper"]}
  :jvm-opts ["-Dorg.neo4j.server.database.location=data/graph.db"]
)
```

But it fails with `WARNING: The key [org.neo4j.server.database.location] is missing from the Neo Server configuration.` and then throws a bunch of exceptions, indicating it did not find a database location.

I tried adding the above JVM opts, and copied the `neo4j-server.properties` to the `resources` folder without any luck.

Answer (score 1):

Neo4j will look for the configuration in `/etc/neo/conf/neo4j-server.properties`. Try putting the 'org.neo4j.server.database.location=data/graph.db' in there.

Comment: No dice: org.apache.commons.configuration.ConfigurationException: Cannot load a configuration from a directory

Answer (score 0):

Or you create your own subclass of CommunityBoostrapper that also accepts the argument from the command line, should be easy enough.

Check my little side project for some hints:

https://github.com/jexp/neo4j-in-memory-server

Comment: I tried like this https://www.refheap.com/85521 but I get the same error as with Jacek's solution: org.apache.commons.configuration.ConfigurationException: Cannot load a configuration from a directory